# CSS for Navigation Menu

Tags: css

I created the following menu with CSS and everything works fine until I get to the dropdown menu.

The hover state works when I hover over the portfolio link but when you go into the sub-menu, the hover state on the main link goes away.

What do I need to do to keep the hover state active on the main link whilst in the submenu?

Driving me crazy trying to figure it out yet it's probably something very simple that I'm overlooking. Thanks in advance. I've added a link to the HTML and CSS code I'm currently using.

http://jsfiddle.net/outlaw5582/PtCtL/1/

HTML:

```html
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li id="active"><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Portfolio</a>
            <ul id="subnavlist">
                <li id="subactive"><a href="cdcovers.html" id="subcurrent" name="subcurrent">CD Covers</a></li>
                <li><a href="logos.html">Logos</a></li>
                <li><a href="flyers.html">Flyers</a></li>
                <li><a href="businesscards.html">Business Cards</a></li>
                <li><a href="photos.html">Photo Enhancements</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#navcontainer {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    height:37px;}

ul#navlist, ul#navlist ul, ul#navlist li {
    list-style-type: none;}

ul#navlist {margin:0 0 30px 0;}

ul#navlist li {display:inline;}

ul#navlist li a {padding: 8px 10px 7px 10px;
    background:#000000;
    border-bottom:3px #00aeef solid;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    margin:0 -3px 0 -2px;}

ul#navlist li a:hover {color:#000;
    background:#00aeef;}

ul#navlist li a:active {color: #000;
    background: #00aeef;}

ul#navlist li a.current {color:#000;
    background:#00aeef;}

ul#subnavlist {display:none;
    text-align:left;
    padding: 5px 9px 0 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    clear:both;
    margin:0 0 0 128px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 4px #000;
    position:relative;
    top:29px;}

ul#subnavlist li {float:none;}

ul#subnavlist li a {background:#A1BF73;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    color:#000;
    height:21px;}

ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist {display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:7px;
    padding-right:0;}

ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist li a {display: block;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 10px 9px 10px;
    margin-left:-9px;
    margin-top:-7px;
    margin-bottom:-5px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    background:#00aeef;}

ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist li a:hover {
    background:#000000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px 10px 9px 10px;}

ul#navlist li:hover {background:#00aeef;}
```

Comment: Your going to have to include your css. You can also use something like http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the css there?

Comment: I tried adding the full CSS code and it says it's too long to post. Here's the basic CSS sections I'm using if that helps at all.`#navcontainer {} ul#navlist, ul#navlist ul, ul#navlist li {} ul#navlist {} ul#navlist li {} ul#navlist li a {} ul#navlist li a:hover {} ul#navlist li a:active {} ul#navlist li a.current {} ul#subnavlist {} ul#subnavlist li {float:none;} ul#subnavlist li a {} ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist {} ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist li a {} ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist li a:hover {} ul#navlist li:hover {}`

Comment: Also, on first glance, your html is incorrect. You should close your ul before your li like this: `<li><a href="">Portfolio</a> <ul id="subnavlist"> ..... </ul> </li>`. You have `</li>` before `</ul>`

Comment: Thank you for that. I wish I could add the entire CSS I'm using but I can't on here. Any ideas?

Comment: Create a fiddle like the first comment that contains all your code, then include that link in your question.

Comment: Link is now provided in the update. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `ul#navlist li a:hover {...` to `ul#navlist li:hover a {...`. This keeps the hover active while inside the submenu.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PtCtL/4/)

Comment: Thank you bunndan, Works perfectly! Your a life saver.